# SQL query with different functions on multiple groupings

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, group-concat

I am trying to compare the revenue of certain items sold to the warranty costs for those items.  The code I have looks something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT od.orderID, pa.partID, pa.price AS revenue, wa.cost AS warcost, co.description AS wardesc
FROM orders od
LEFT OUTER JOIN parts pa ON pa.orderID = od.orderID
LEFT OUTER JOIN warranties wa ON pa.partID = wa.partID
LEFT OUTER JOIN malfunctions ml ON ml.malfID = wa.malfID
LEFT OUTER JOIN components co ON ml.compID = co.compID
```

which returns something like the below.

```
orderID  | partID | revenue |   warcost |   wardesc<br>
1   |   1001    | 100   |   45  |   Issue #1<br>
1   |   1001 |  100  | 50  | Issue #2<br>
1   |   1002 |  200  | 55    |  Issue #3<br>
2   |   1003 |  300  | 65    |  Issue #3<br>
2   |   1003 |  300  | 70    |  Issue #4
```

Grouping by order, I would like to SUM the warcost, but only SUM the revenue by individual partID's, so the revenue is not counted twice.  I have found this impossible to do!

End result should like the below, look forward to some assistance!

```
orderID |   partID |        revenue |   warcost |   wardesc<br>
1 |     1001,1002    | 300   |  150  |  Issue #1, Issue #2, Issue #3<br>
2    |  1003     |  300  |  135  |  Issue #3, Issue #4
```

Comment: Is this in mysql? And consider expanding a little on the revenue calculations you want to do.

Comment: Yes, this is in mysql.  For revenue, sorry if I was not clear.  The goal is simply to add the revenue for the parts in each order - but simply using SUM(revenue) has led to double counting parts 1001 and 1003 in this example.

Comment: I added an answer, that makes sense if your results are those when you do that query, let me know if you still see duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT od.orderID,
  GROUP_CONCAT(pa.partID) AS parts,
  SUM(pa.price) AS revenue,
  SUM(wa.cost) AS warcost,
  GROUP_CONCAT(co.description) AS wardesc
FROM orders od
LEFT OUTER JOIN parts pa ON pa.orderID = od.orderID
LEFT OUTER JOIN warranties wa ON pa.partID = wa.partID
LEFT OUTER JOIN malfunctions ml ON ml.malfID = wa.malfID
LEFT OUTER JOIN components co ON ml.compID = co.compID
GROUP BY od.orderID
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec74f/1)</kbd> ( this is a simplification of what you have, based on the results of your query)

---

EDIT:

Getting duplicate values is probably because you might have multiple matches in one or more of those joins. If you see that you can't remove the duplicates and your original query has the correct results you can do:

```
SELECT orderID,
  GROUP_CONCAT(partID),
  SUM(revenue),
  SUM(warcost),
  GROUP_CONCAT(wardesc)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT od.orderID AS orderID,
    pa.partID AS partID,
    pa.price AS revenue,
    wa.cost AS warcost,
    co.description AS wardesc
  FROM orders od
  LEFT OUTER JOIN parts pa ON pa.orderID = od.orderID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN warranties wa ON pa.partID = wa.partID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN malfunctions ml ON ml.malfID = wa.malfID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN components co ON ml.compID = co.compID
  ) a
GROUP BY orderID
```

Comment: Unfortunately simply doing this is what leads to double counting the revenue for parts 1001 and 1003.  It lists the revenue for order #1 as $400 and for order #2 as $600 (instead of $300 and $300)

Comment: @MateoR. I updated my answer. This should give you the results you are expecting, but you might want to check those joins one by one to see if you can find the source of the duplicates and try to mitigate it.

Comment: That was an interesting attempt, but no luck!  The reason for the duplicates is that the same part may have had more than one warranty issue (ie. the duplicates themselves are not a mistake).  That is why part 1001 and 1003 get double counted when summing the revenue.  Does that clear things up somewhat?

Comment: Yes. it does :). Then, instead of joining with warranties directly, try joining with `(SELECT distinct partID FROM warranties) wa ON pa.partID = wa.PartID`. Try it on the first query, before i update the answer. if it doesn't work we try something else.

Comment: I had to do "LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT partID, cost, malfID
FROM warranties) wa ON pa.partID = wa.partID".  Hope that's what you meant, but still did not work with the revenue being counted twice.  I am concerned though that if we only take the distinct values, we will lose warcost data.

Comment: I thought I had an answer with "LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT partID, SUM(cost) AS cost, malfID FROM warranties GROUP BY partID) wa ON pa.partID = wa.partID"  This seems to give the right values for warranties and revenue.  But - I am losing the malfID information by doing a GROUP BY here.  Maybe this is a helpful step though?

Comment: Yes. i think it is. You probably want to try and join malfunctions and components also inside that select to try to figure out a way of removing the duplicate values. the sum(cost) is the first step. Now you have to make sure that from that select you return only unique id's to join with parts table.

Comment: I gave up!  Ultimately decided to do GROUP_CONCAT for both revenue and partID, and doing some PHP post-processing from there.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. As long as you fixed your problem that's good.. Don't know if you should mark this answer as accepted or not, as it wasn't a complete solution for your problem. I'll leave it to you. :)